# When does a new buff or a new malus apply if there is a battle underway?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Let say one of these things happens while I paused the game and a fight has been started :

- I upgrade my troops for better units
- I get a new military technology / idea that modify my army

**Will the new buff or malus will apply on my troops during their fight or after it ?**

Comment: When I say "malus", I'm thinking of the temporary moral drop when you upgrade your troop to better ones.

Comment: Great question!  I'm fairly certain the changes will take effect immediately, but I'm not where I can confirm that right now.  If you're sitting in the scenario right now, it should be fairly safe to test by taking a technology upgrade since you can do that and receive the buffs to military tactics/etc., but you don't have to actually upgrade your troop type right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It applies immediately.

If you change unit type, then you'll get low morale right during the battle. The same goes with acquiring and losing tactic, combat ability and discipline bonuses. It doesn't matter what's the source - advisers, policies, new tech, ideas.

One exception - morale bonus. It only increases max morale, and you need some time to replenish it.

P.S. I don't have a proof link, but I have fist-hand experience with it. I tested it thoroughly with Common Sense 1.12.1, and I continue to observe this during recent campaigns, the latest being 1.16

Comment: Could you include the version used to test it, for future reference?

Comment: @mafu, done - I first did it with Common Sense, and it works this way with the recent version - 1.16